# Cannot get values for IOptions<T>, values always null in Console App (.net Core 2.2.)

Tags: .net, .net-core, configuration

I have Console App for .NET Core 2.2. I have `appsettings.json` where `MailSettings` are defined. I have created POCO class `MailSettings`. I have added `.AddOptions` to configuration and I want to be able to access `IOptions<MailSettings>`, but values are always null.
My code is below.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
...

class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Setup Config --------------------------------------------------------------
            IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
                        .Build();

         
            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
            serviceCollection.AddOptions();
          
            serviceCollection.Configure<MailSettings>(config.GetSection(nameof(MailSettings)));

           
           
            serviceCollection.AddScoped<IStep, Step>();

            var services = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

            var step = services.GetService<IStep>();
            step.Process();

            // todo: change to Autfac                
            //var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
            //containerBuilder.Populate(serviceCollection);
            //containerBuilder.RegisterType<Step>().As<IStep>();
            //var container = containerBuilder.Build();
            //var serviceProvider = new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
        }
    }
```

I have appsettings.json with the following settings:

```
"MailSettings": {
    "MailServer": "smtp.test.com",
    "MailSender": "test@test.com"
  },
```

MailSettings class:

```
    public class MailSettings
    {
        public string MailServer { get; set; }
        public string MailSender { get; set; }
    }

Class Step that should use IOptions<MailSettings>, but values are NULL all the time.

{
    public interface IStep
    {
        void Process();
    }

    public class Step : IStep
    {
        public Step(IOptions<MailSettings> opt)
        {
            var op = opt.Value; // VALUES ARE NULL, WHY?
        }

        public void Process()
        {

        }
    }
```

P.S. Secondly I would need to rewrite it for using AutoFac as dependency injection container, will it make additional problems?

Comment: Maybe you simply missed ```.Configure<T>()```? [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options)

Answer (score 4):

Right click on your `appsetting.json` file in Visual Studio and select properties.

Then change the `Copy to Output Directory` to **Copy if newer**